# Lower text in a QMessagebox

Tags: qt, settext, qmessagebox

I have a QMessagebox with a custom background image. Since there is some stuff on the top side of the background image I want to see, the text of the messagebox should be lowered. Does anybody know how I can do this? I already tried throwing in some white lines using br, so:

```
popup.setText("<font size =5 color =white ><br>""<br>""<br>""Are you sure you 
want to erase the memory</font> ");
```

but this screws up the background picture. Is there any way I can move the "box" that contains the text to a lower position?

Comment: well this piece of code should lower text position by 3 lines..

Comment: It does, but it screws up my background. Well actually the problem is when I use popup.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(hello.png)) it sets the background of not only the messagebox, but also the buttons and the text box. So is there a way to set just the background of the messagebox and not of its components?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to get the QMessageBox' layout, get the label which holds your text and increment the labels margin. This probably is a hack and might make your project unportable. Construct your QMessageBox, call hack and then exec the box.

```
void hack(QMessageBox* pMessageBox)
{
   QGridLayout* grid = qobject_cast<QGridLayout*>(pMessageBox->layout());
   if (grid)
   {
      QLabel* label = qobject_cast<QLabel*>((grid->itemAtPosition(0,1))->widget());
      if (label)
      {
         label->setMargin(label->margin()+5); // whatever is suitable
      }
   }
}
```